# Cannot assign "<TheModel>": "RelatedModel.the_model" must be a "TheModel" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a ForeignKey field on what we'll call `RelatedModel`, which references what we'll call `TheModel`. The ORM is completely freaking out when I try to access instances of `RelatedModel` through an instance of `TheModel`, example:

```
the_model_instance.related_models.all()
ValueError: Cannot assign "<TheModel: 403:>": "RelatedModel.the_model" must be a "TheModel" instance.

the_model_instance.related_models.create()
ValueError: Cannot assign "<TheModel: 403:>": "RelatedModel.the_model" must be a "TheModel" instance.
```

I can still get instances of `RelatedModel` via the Manager just fine, but it'd be a shame to lose the convenience/syntax of getting them through the parent. Has anyone encountered this before/ have any ideas??

Also the relationship is pretty standard:

```
class RelatedModel(models.Model):
     the_model = models.ForeignKey(TheModel, related_name='related_models', null=False)
```

EDIT - it's also not always an issue, sometimes when I restart my shell it works, then it stops working later on, I'm losing my mind ahhhhhhh

Comment: are you sure you are importing both models when you restart shell ?

Comment: auto imports all of them - could it be my autoreload that's botching it?

Comment: May be. Just can't think of any other idea. try changing names of model may be Django is getting confused for using keywords, again this is unlikely but worth a shot